# Performing EDA on a dataset with missing features

Tags: data-cleaning, visualization, exploratory-factor-analysis

I'm new to DS.

I want to perform EDA on such dataset, where these are the missing features stats of my train and test sets:

- train:

  Test_0        0
  Test_1       31
  Test_2        0
  Test_3      141
  Test_4        0
  Test_5        0
  Test_6        0
  Test_7        0
  Test_8     1045
  Test_9        0
  Test_10       0
  Test_11       0
  Test_12       0
  Test_13       0
  Test_14       0
  Test_15    2967
  Class         0
  dtype: int64
- test:

  Test_0       0
  Test_1       7
  Test_2       0
  Test_3      46
  Test_4       0
  Test_5       0
  Test_6       0
  Test_7       0
  Test_8     279
  Test_9       0
  Test_10      0
  Test_11      0
  Test_12      0
  Test_13      0
  Test_14      0
  Test_15    738
  dtype: int64

I have 3616 data lines in total on my train set and 905 on my test set.
How can I decide on which features to "throw away" and which to "fill" artificially (and how to fill - I read a bit about mean filling etc.)

If anyone can also point me to a guide that explains this issues I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of techniques through which you can fill the missing values. Some of them are:

1.) Replacing with mean, median or mode as you correctly pointed out.

2.) Replacing with a constant value like 0

3.) [KNN Imputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html)

4.) [Iterative Imputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html)

Which ones to use depends on what kind of data you have. Or you can try all and see which gives you best results

Cheers!